# Eliyahu HaNovi and Moshiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, eliyahu-hanavi

The Midrash says that Eliyahu HaNovi will come three days beforehand to announce the Mashiach's arrival.

Does anyone know where this Medrash is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [here, ref. 2](http://www.aharit.com/A-06.php) that it is a [Pesikta Rabosi (end of Chapter 35)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39324&pgnum=350). The statement is not without its questions as the extensive note points out.

> פסיקתא רבתי: "מה נאוו על ההדים רגלי מבשר. בשעה שהקב"ה גואל את ישראל,
>   **שלושה ימים קודם שיבוא המשיח, בא אליהו הנביא** ועומד על הרי ישראל ובוכה ומספיד עליהם ואומר: הרי ארץ ישראל עד מתי אתם עומדים בארץ ציה
>   ושממה. וקולו נשמע בכל העולם, אחר כך יאמר בא שלום לעולם, בא שלום לעולם,
>   שנאמר מה נאוו על ההרים רגלי מבשר משמיע שלום. ביום שני בא ועומד על הרי
>   ישראל ואומר באה טובה לעולם, באה טובה עולם, שנאמר מבשר טוב, ביום השלישי
>   בא ועומד על הרי ישראל ואומר באה ישועה לעולם, באה ישועה לעולם, שנאמר
>   משמיע ישועה אומר לציון מלך אלקיך

.

Comment: A more specific source is found here:  ------- במדרש רבה (דברים ג, טז) נאמר: "בשעה שהקב"ה גואל את ישראל, קודם שלושה ימים שיבוא משיח, בא אליהו ועומד על הרי ישראל... ואחר-כך אומר להם: בא שלום לעולם, שנאמר הנה על ההרים רגלי מבשר משמיע שלום (נחום ב,א)... באותה שעה מראה הקב"ה את כבודו ומלכותו לכל באי עולם וגואל את ישראל ונגלה בראשם". - See more at: http://chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=7025&CategoryID=1419#sthash.gGzhhYXS.dpuf

Comment: @Menachem: I looked at a physical copy of Devarim Rabbah, but I could not find. Do you know where it could possibly be?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah: I'll see if I can find it. Here it is in Yalkut Shimoni 475 - Yeshayahu Chapter 52: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=12&perek=52&mefaresh=shimoni

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah: It may be a misprint, or a different version of the Midrash Rabbah. The end of section 17 talks about Eliyahu coming, but doesn't mention 3 days before: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=180